# How to derive a parent class?

Tags: system-verilog

#1

To understand the behavior of `new()` and inheritance, I made a simple class and added `class child_class`:

//   Example 1

```
class parent_class;
  logic [31:0] addr;
  logic [7:0] data;
  bit parity;
  
  function new(logic [31:0] add, logic [7:0] dat);
 
    addr = add;
    data = dat;
  endfunction
endclass

class child_class extends parent_class;
  bit [31:0] data;
  static int count;
  
  function new();
    count++;
    data = count;
  endfunction
endclass


module inheritence;
  initial begin
    
    parent_class p; 
    p = new(32'h1234, 8'hff);
    $display("Value of addr = %0d data = %0d",p.addr,p.data);
    p.addr = 10;
    p.data = 20;
    $display("Value of addr = %0d data = %0d",p.addr,p.data);
  end
endmodule
```

But, when I executed it, I got the error message:

```
 class child_class extends parent_class;
                                      |
xmvlog: *E,FAABP1 (testbench.sv,21|38): Task/function call, or property/sequence instance does not specify all required formal arguments.
  function new(logic [31:0] add, logic [7:0] dat);
```

Q1. Why can't I make the child class? How do I correctly derive the class and use it?

#2

If I remove `class child_class` in my code above,

```
   class parent_class;
      logic [31:0] addr;
      logic [7:0] data;
      bit parity;
      
      function new(logic [31:0] add, logic [7:0] dat);
     
        addr = add;
        data = dat;
      endfunction
    endclass
    
    
    module inheritence;
      initial begin
        
        parent_class p; 
        p = new(32'h1234, 8'hff);
        $display("Value of addr = %0d data = %0d",p.addr,p.data);
        p.addr = 10;
        p.data = 20;
        $display("Value of addr = %0d data = %0d",p.addr,p.data);
      end
    endmodule
```

There is no error message for child class. What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 8.7 *Constructors*:

> The **new** method of a derived class shall first call its base class
> constructor [**super.new**() as described in 8.15].

From section 8.15 *Super*:

> A **super.new** call shall be the first statement executed in the
> constructor. This is because the superclass shall be initialized
> before the current class and, if the user code does not provide an
> initialization, the compiler shall insert a call to **super.new**
> automatically.

The error message is telling you that the `new` function in the `child_class` class is implicitly making a call to the `new` function in the `parent_class` class, but that `new` function requires 2 arguments.

One way to fix the error is to explicitly call `spuer.new` in `child_class` with 2 arguments.  For example, this code fixes the error:

```
class child_class extends parent_class;
  bit [31:0] data;
  static int count;
  
  function new();
    super.new(0, data);
    count++;
    data = count;
  endfunction
endclass
```

You must decide if this how you want your code to behave.

To answer the 2nd question, since you no longer have the derived class (`child_class`) which has the syntax error, you no longer get an error.  Your module properly calls `new` from `parent_class` with the correct number of arguments (2).

Answer (score -2):

1. I am not from system-verilog and from C C++/shell.
   Assume that I created a character variable "testing" and I am not using that variable anywhere inside my program. Due to that, one byte wasted when my program at execution mode.
   Assume that I wrote that in a server program inside an infinite loop.
   In this case, it will affect the performance of server program since it is using a variable which is not being used.
   Hence wastage of memory.
   This may affect other program when that program is waiting for free space at RAM/cache from disk.
   Hence better to remove all warnings when we obtain during compilation.
   This is applicable to all living beings at each planet/universe handling the space across the planets/universe [if applicable:) ]
2. You need to learn parent class, constructor, destructor/uploaded functions at parent/child class when performing inheritance.
   `https://www.chipverify.com/systemverilog/systemverilog-inheritance`